# Kernel min freq jumping with the scaling

Tags: android, kernel, frequency

CAF kernel 3.18.132 min freq is jumping from minimum value to the scaling result...

For example, let's assume I have a kernel with minimum freq 500 MHz and max 2.0 GHz. When the kernel wants to scale to 1.5 GHz, the minimum freq also changes to 1.5 GHz, then resets back to 500 MHz. Is that a normal behavior? I personally don't have any problem with this, but it takes a bit more time for the minimum value to get at 500 MHz again, which makes the kernel stay on 1.5 GHz for longer, and I think this makes the scaling ineffective in battery and normal behavior.

If this question doesn't make much sense, sorry. I just want to know if this is concerning for the battery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, that's actually caused by the ROM itself. Using Android 8 or up will show this behavior. I still don't see the point in this "feature".